# Reading package lists... Error! - Freya

Tags: release-freya, updates

This is the information I get when I try `sudo apt-get update` or when I try to use the Package Manager.

```
Reading package lists... Error!
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I tried following one of the answers I found here by doing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:versable/elementary-update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

but it did not help me. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got two errors trying to update.

First of all, an error with a bad signature. All repositories in Ubuntu are signed with a GPG key, to check its authenticity. Look at the key *40976EAF437D05B5* near the expression *BADSIG*. You must download the correct signature from the keyserver with this command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5
```

To solve the problem with *MergeList*, make a copy of your apt-lists. From terminal, try:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists_old
sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists/ /var/lib/apt/lists_old
```

Now, remove the wrong lists:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

and finally, recreate the *apt-lists* with:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Glad to read it. You're welcome